# Select highest revision from table for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table setup like this

```
ID JOBID REPORTNAME REVISION PDFLOCATION

1  1     RPT1       1        /var/rpt1.pdf
1  2     RPT2       1        /var/rpt2.pdf
1  1     RPT1       2        /var/rpt3.pdf
```

How do I select all the rows but I want only the highest revision per `jobid`
and example result from the query should be

```
1  2     RPT2       1        /var/rpt2.pdf
1  1     RPT1       2        /var/rpt3.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select the record having the maximum revision number for each `ID`/`JOBID` group.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, JOBID, MAX(REVISION) AS REVISION
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID, JOBID
) t2
    ON t1.ID       = t2.ID AND
       t1.JOBID    = t2.JOBID AND
       t1.REVISION = t2.REVISION
```

Comment: Happy to help you out :-)